# Botframework email channel

Tags: azure, email, botframework, bots

I try to set up the email channel for a bot on the Azure portal using a company email address. The address uses password authentication. When I try to save I receive `Unable to save. Unable to validate the given credentials. ID: b8f65400c0bbb04890efdfa2950940d1`. Is this supposed to work?

If I use a company test tenant with an email address ending in `onmicrosoft.com` registration succeeds.

The only difference I see when doing one of the connection tests on https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ (Mailbox provisioning test) is that I get a company login page with the company email address and the standard Microsoft prompt with the `onmicrosoft` account.

Answer (score 1):

There may be another way, but for my organization, we found the same thing and the solution was for us to create an `onmicrosoft.com` email address to use for the email channel for the bot. It shouldn't actually matter if you only have access to do this in the test tenant; all you're doing is setting up a channel to communicate with the bot, and you can give you bot access to connect to your production tenant if there are functions there you need.

Comment: Thanks very much, good to know. In my case, however, it does matter because I need the address to be in the same tenant as the bot. 

Eventually I want to send notfications from a Nintex workflow and if that notification originates from assigning a workflow task it has to be in the same tenant or the task wouldn't be assigned.

Comment: Is the email an O365/Exchange email address? It doesn't have to be onmicrosoft.com specifically, but it does need to be O365 or Exchange. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-email?view=azure-bot-service-4.0